# s7.NET error tryind to read or write a var in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, siemens, s7-1200

When i try to read some value appear de error on image...
I already tried diferent ways and the result it´s all time the same(comment lines).
How i can read a value in vb.net and s7.1200?
thanks

[error vb.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP20z.png)

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports S7.Net

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Imports System.Data
Imports VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Threading
Module PLC_InOut
    Public Sub PLCInOuts()
        '  Dim Result As BitArray()

        ' Result = PLC.Read("DB8.DBW0")
        '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\Inputs
        ' Result = PLC.Read(DataType.DataBlock, 8, 0, VarType.Bit, 0, 16)
        'Result = PLC.Read(DataType.DataBlock, 8, 0, VarType.Byte, 1, 0)
        ' Result = PLC.Read("DB7.DBX0.0")
        'Dim Value1 As Byte = PLC.Read("DB8.DBW0")
        Dim u1 As System.UInt16 = PLC.Read("DB8.DBW0")
        Dim b1() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(u1)


        If test1_out Then

            '   PLC.Write(DataType.Output, 0, 0, VarType.Bit, True)
            'PLC.Write("O0.0", 1)
            'PLC.Write("%M47.6", True)
            '  PLC.Write("DB7.DBX0.0", True)
            'PLC.WriteBit(DataType.DataBlock, 7, 0, 0, True)
        End If
        ' ("db8.dbx0.0")
        '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\outputs
        '   PLC.WriteBit(DataType.DataBlock, 7, 0, 0, test1_out)
    End Sub
End Module
```

[plc var_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gSfr.png)

Comment: What is the tag defined as in the PLC?

Comment: David, thanks!
already added a plc program picture

Comment: https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/WW/en/posts/s7-net-plcexception/287535

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the plc hardware was not completely downloaded after changed the plc proprieties-protection & security parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).